# How do I make a sliding box in HTML5 that is like this website https://thecubicle.us/?

Tags: html, css

So, i want to make a sliding box like this website:"https://thecubicle.us/". How do i do this is HTML5? If there is some other language involved, please be helpful to me because HTML is the only programming language that I know.

Thanks, 
PleaseHelpMeImANoob2

Comment: Downvotes are due to no attempt.

Comment: Sorry, but this is my first time ever making a question on Stack Overflow, and I might not be good at first, but I will get better. As you can see now, my username applies to my coding skills and doing pretty much anything on Stack Overflow. Thanks for making me upset. I like it a lot. I am sorry if I am being rude, but this is my first time doing this. You should be able to tell that I am a a newbie level for coding, and you say that no one will answer me due to all of these downvotes. Thanks a lot. Sorry if I am sounding rude when you are reading this but I am a newbie.

Comment: Its ok to be new, but the question is just not a good one for this site. Please refer to the help center on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code and use it:

```html
You can take the following code for your query:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
       <!-- <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">-->
         <center>
           <h1>First Image</h1>
        </center>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
       <!-- <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">-->
        <center>
           <h1>Second Image</h1>
        </center>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <!--<img src="ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">-->
        <center>
           <h1>Third Image</h1>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just place the desired image in the anchor tag which I have hided from the code and your sliding box will appear.